# Field level security pain in Apex tests when using packaging 2

Tags: apex, unit-test, managed-package, field-level-security, packaging-2

In line with current security standards, we use `with security_enforced` extensively in our code. When doing CI (Continuous Integration) builds or working interactively we use `sfdx force:user:permset:assign` to assign permission sets that grant the field level access so the Apex tests pass. And when our product is installed no tests are run so no problem there.

But packaging 2 creates the packaging org on the fly and runs the Apex tests with no hook point to do any org preparation. So what strategy works to get the right field level permissions set?

- Duplicate all the permissions in the `Admin.profile-meta.xml`?

  - This assumes that the packaging process does use that profile. Does it?
  - And that the `Admin.profile-meta.xml` is applied in the packaging org. Is it?
- Assign the permission sets programatically in the `@TestSetup` method of every test? But that then has `MIXED_DML_OPERATION` challenges.
- Modify the product code to not do security checks when tests are running. (Yuk.)
- Better approaches?

We are getting test failures on packaging related to custom fields we add to the `Event` object and are trying to figure out why.

Comment: I must say, we do cheat and turn off checks in test executions. We do this via use of our own class that delegates to the standard schema checks. This as a major downside that Checkmarx flags *everything* as not applying CRUD/FLS checks because it does shallow code path analysis.

Comment: Yeah Phil, sometimes the pragmatic approach is necessary when the options narrow down too much in Salesforce.

Comment: @PhilW You don't need to "cheat" anymore, there's an official path you can take to avoid this problem of yours.

Comment: Yes, good for 2GP. Our cheating originates in 1GP. We should break the habit though ;)

Comment: @PhilW Yeah, we ourselves are stuck on 1GMP until they provide a solid 2GMP migration path. Supposedly might be available in 2022 or so. Our package needed this like last year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify permission sets to use for version creation. A snippet is provided in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_unpackaged_md.htm).

```
"packageDirectories": [
    {
        "path": "force-app",
        "package": "TV_unl", 
        "versionName": "ver 0.1",
        "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
        "default": true, 
        "unpackagedMetadata": {
            "path": "my-unpackaged-directory"
        },
        "apexTestAccess": {
               "permissionSets": [
                   "Permission_Set_1",
                   "Permission_Set_2"
               ],
               "permissionSetLicenses": [
                   "SalesConsoleUser"
               ]
           }

    }, 
    {
        "path": "my-unpackaged-directory",
        "default": false
    }
]
```

This means that you won't need to write permissions into your tests, you won't need to intentionally dumb down security and risk false security flags in Checkmarx, and you'll eliminate most of your challenges when building new versions of your packages.

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I need. Glad someone reads the docs...